# I want change element of an array with another element of different array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, dom, input

There is an input field and if a user presses "i", input gets masked with a message.
I try to create an array that contains the message. I try to iterate over input with this array and I failed.

Here is my failure;

```js
const msg = ['Peter please answer the following question.'];
const dest = [...msg];
petition.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e.key === 'i') {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      console.log((dest[i] = petition.value[i]));
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="petition" type="text">
```

Comment: I've updated your question with valid JavaScript and the minimal HTML needed to make this work. It's not clear what you're expecting to happen. You're logging the result of setting the `i`th element of `dest` to the `i`th character of the textbox, which will be the `i`th character of the textbox, which is great if your textbox has at least ten characters in it by the time you press "i".

Comment: Thank you for your response. :) Actually I am trying to mask the input value. In website of peteranswers.com,  it is a faked fortune tell website to have fun, when you press '.' the input that user types is changed with a message. I was trying to duplicate that function.